# SpringBoot 1.2 resteasy3.0.8 is not loading static html page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, resteasy

Am working on a springboot 1.2 with resteasy 3.0.8 version. Am not able to access the static html page which is present in the /target/classes/static location, getting 404
The URL am trying to access is:
//
localhost:8080/insightsdmgr/UploadModel1.html

[image]